# Excluding results from grep

Tags: command-line

So I have a project under svn and I'm searching the file contents. In the result set I get .svn files that I don't want actually to see. for example:

```
$ grep -i -r "breadcrumb" . -l
./terms_and_conditions/.svn/text-base/index.tpl.svn-base
./terms_and_conditions/.svn/tmp/index.tpl.tmp 
./terms_and_conditions/.svn/tmp/index.tpl.3.tmp
./terms_and_conditions/.svn/tmp/index.tpl.2.tmp
./terms_and_conditions/index.tpl
./privacy/.svn/text-base/index.tpl.svn-base
./privacy/.svn/tmp/index.tpl.tmp
./privacy/.svn/tmp/index.tpl.3.tmp
./privacy/.svn/tmp/index.tpl.2.tmp
./privacy/index.tpl
```

how can I exclude the files under ".svn" directories from the result set so that I only get

```
./terms_and_conditions/index.tpl
./privacy/index.tpl
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pipe those through:

```
grep -v '/\.svn/'
```

Comment: Works like a charm. But why '/\.svn/' and not ".svn"?

Comment: You could simply use "svn"; it's not likely that you've used svn in your file names.

Comment: @Joe If you don't surround it by slashes or have the dot, it could match other things with "svn" in their path... And @Nerdling I don't see the value in *not* matching accurately when it's so easy, however unlikely.